# Handshake failed in Pidgin

Tags: arch-linux, pidgin, nss

I am trying to connect to our in-house XMPP server using piding in Arch Linux, but I always get `SSL Handshake Failed` error in Pidgin.

These are the error lines I get when running `pidgin -d`:

```
(10:52:25) jabber: Sending (user@host): <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
(10:52:25) jabber: Recv (50): <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
(10:52:25) nss: Handshake failed  (-12173)
(10:52:25) connection: Connection error on 0x16385f0 (reason: 5 description: SSL Handshake Failed)
(10:52:25) account: Disconnecting account user@host/ (0x1820c60)
```

I searched for that nss error, and found [here](https://mozilla.github.io/python-nss-docs/nss.error-module.html) that this error means that server is using some kind of insecure key exchange (I suppose).

Anyway, I tried `ssltap -s -p 5222 host:5222` and pointed Pidgin to `localhost:5222` to get the log of handshake, and this is it:

```
Connected to HOST:5222
--> [
<?xml version='1.0' ?><stream:stream to='HOST' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>]
<-- [
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="HOST" id="7d2b1460" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">]
<-- [
<stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><required/></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>]
--> [
<starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>]
<-- [
<proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>]
--> [
(151 bytes of 146)
SSLRecord { [Wed Feb 24 10:44:10 2016]
   type    = 22 (handshake)
   version = { 3,1 }
   length  = 146 (0x92)
   handshake {
      type = 1 (client_hello)
      length = 142 (0x00008e)
         ClientHelloV3 {
            client_version = {3, 3}
            random = {...}
            session ID = {
                length = 0
                contents = {...}
            }
            cipher_suites[17] = {
                (0xc02b) TLS/ECDHE-ECDSA/AES128-GCM/SHA256
                (0xc02f) TLS/ECDHE-RSA/AES128-GCM/SHA256
                (0xc00a) TLS/ECDHE-ECDSA/AES256-CBC/SHA
                (0xc009) TLS/ECDHE-ECDSA/AES128-CBC/SHA
                (0xc013) TLS/ECDHE-RSA/AES128-CBC/SHA
                (0xc027) TLS/ECDHE-RSA/AES128-CBC/SHA256
                (0xc014) TLS/ECDHE-RSA/AES256-CBC/SHA
                (0xc007) TLS/ECDHE-ECDSA/RC4-128/SHA
                (0xc011) TLS/ECDHE-RSA/RC4-128/SHA
                (0x009e) TLS/DHE-RSA/AES128-GCM/SHA256
                (0x0033) TLS/DHE-RSA/AES128-CBC/SHA
                (0x0032) TLS/DHE-DSS/AES128-CBC/SHA
                (0x0067) TLS/DHE-RSA/AES128-CBC/SHA256
                (0x0039) TLS/DHE-RSA/AES256-CBC/SHA
                (0x006b) TLS/DHE-RSA/AES256-CBC/SHA256
                (0x002f) TLS/RSA/AES128-CBC/SHA
                (0x0035) TLS/RSA/AES256-CBC/SHA
            }
            compression[1] = {
                (00) NULL
            }
            extensions[67] = {
              extension type server_name, length [14] = {
   0: 00 0c 00 00  09 6c 6f 63  61 6c 68 6f  73 74        | .....localhost
              }
              extension type renegotiation_info, length [1] = {
   0: 00                                                  | .
              }
              extension type elliptic_curves, length [8] = {
   0: 00 06 00 17  00 18 00 19                            | ........
              }
              extension type ec_point_formats, length [2] = {
   0: 01 00                                               | ..
              }
              extension type signature_algorithms, length [22] = {
   0: 00 14 04 01  05 01 06 01  02 01 04 03  05 03 06 03  | ................
  10: 02 03 04 02  02 02                                  | ......
              }
            }
         }
   }
}
]
<-- [
(2778 bytes of 2773)
SSLRecord { [Wed Feb 24 10:44:10 2016]
   type    = 22 (handshake)
   version = { 3,1 }
   length  = 2773 (0xad5)
   handshake {
      type = 2 (server_hello)
      length = 70 (0x000046)
         ServerHello {
            server_version = {3, 1}
            random = {...}
            session ID = {
                length = 32
                contents = {...}
            }
            cipher_suite = (0x0033) TLS/DHE-RSA/AES128-CBC/SHA
            compression method = (00) NULL
         }
      type = 11 (certificate)
      length = 2135 (0x000857)
         CertificateChain {
            chainlength = 2132 (0x0854)
            Certificate {
               size = 925 (0x039d)
               data = { saved in file 'cert.001' }
            }
            Certificate {
               size = 1201 (0x04b1)
               data = { saved in file 'cert.002' }
            }
         }
      type = 12 (server_key_exchange)
      length = 552 (0x000228)
      type = 14 (server_hello_done)
      length = 0 (0x000000)
   }
}
]
--> [
(7 bytes of 2)
SSLRecord { [Wed Feb 24 10:44:10 2016]
   type    = 21 (alert)
   version = { 3,1 }
   length  = 2 (0x2)
   fatal: illegal_parameter
}
]
Read EOF on Client socket. [Wed Feb 24 10:44:10 2016]
Read EOF on Server socket. [Wed Feb 24 10:44:10 2016]
```

Seems like server and client agreed on `TLS/DHE-RSA/AES128-CBC/SHA`, but client failed then. Is that it? I have added `cert.001` and `cert.002` to Certificates in Pidgin, but that doesn't help.

Because it is an in-house server, I don't need the security and I don't care about it. I modified account setting in Pidgin to `Use encryption if available` and also `Allow plaintext auth over unencrypted streams` but it does not work.

Any help on how to make Pidgin (or NSS) to accept my server is very appreciated.

Output of `pidgin --version`

```
Pidgin 2.10.12 (libpurple 2.10.12)
```

Output of `pacman -Qi nss`

```
Name            : nss
Version         : 3.22-1
Description     : Mozilla Network Security Services
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/
Licenses        : MPL  GPL
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : nspr>=4.10.10  sqlite  zlib  sh  p11-kit
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : atom-editor  firefox  jre8-openjdk-headless  libnm-glib  libpurple  qca-qt4  qca-qt5
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 5.80 MiB
Packager        : Jan Alexander Steffens (heftig) <jan.steffens@gmail.com>
Build Date      : Fri Feb 5 15:09:40 2016
Install Date    : Mon Feb 22 17:13:39 2016
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : Yes
Validated By    : Signature
```

*EDIT*:

I forgot to mention that I do not have access to server, so I can not change anything there.

Comment: The fatal parameter error means, "A field in the handshake was out of range or inconsistent with other fields.  This message is always fatal." from http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#appendix-A.3  - this feels more like an application issue than a linux issue, may do better on SuperUser?

Comment: How may I move question to SuperUser?

Comment: I just forgot to mention that I have another Pidgin running on Ubuntu 12.04 which is working fine. I think the version is `2.10.3` or something like that, but I am not in workplace. I will confirm that when I get there.